# Azure AD B2C Custom Policy: obtaining newUser attribute

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have some questions regarding AAD B2C Custom Policies. So here is my problem, I want to obtain the `newUser` attribute but I am not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

This was my first solution, the purpose for this technical profile is the signup part, I've tried putting the `newUser` as an `Output` claim here. But I realize it does not work due to it being in `SM-Noop`.

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="NewUserAccountUpdatePrimaryDetails">
          <DisplayName>Profile creation using read only email</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
            <Item Key="language.button_continue">Next</Item>
            <!-- Sample: Remove sign-up email verification -->
            <Item Key="EnforceEmailVerification">False</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaimsTransformations>
            <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateReadonlyEmailClaim" />
          </InputClaimsTransformations>
          <InputClaims>
            <!--Sample: Set input the ReadOnlyEmail claim type to prefilled the email address-->
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readOnlyEmail" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="country" />
            <!-- Optional claims, to be collected from the user -->
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="streetAddress" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="city" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="state" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="postalCode" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readOnlyEmail" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="country" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName"  Required="true"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" Required="true"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" Required="true"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />
            <!-- Optional claims, to be collected from the user -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="streetAddress" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="city" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="state" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="postalCode" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail-ProfileUpdate" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Now for the second solution I've tried is to declare the `newUser` as `Output` claim in `RelyingParty`.

```xml
<RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="CheckPassReset" />
    <UserJourneyBehaviors>
      <SingleSignOn Scope="Tenant" />
      <JourneyInsights TelemetryEngine="ApplicationInsights" InstrumentationKey="4b408c9c-6ef1-43db-82e7-6368e1fc1536"
      DeveloperMode="true" ClientEnabled="false" ServerEnabled="true" TelemetryVersion="1.0.0" />
      <ScriptExecution>Allow</ScriptExecution>
    </UserJourneyBehaviors>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
```

Where did I go wrong with this? Most of the solutions I've seen in Google and StackOverflow is related to `User Flow`. I've probably missed something but I don't know what.

Thank you for the help! If you need any more information, please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the custom policy starter pack, the `newUser` claim is produced by the technical profile that creates the user (`AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail`):

```xml
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" PartnerClaimType="newClaimsPrincipalCreated" />
```

It is running a write operation against the Graph API, and if this creates a new user, `newClaimsPrincipalCreated` returns true.
The above output claim then maps this to the `newUser` claim, that you then use in the following steps.

In your example, `AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail-ProfileUpdate` sounds like a write done while updating the user's profile.
If in this case the user already exists, the `newUser` claim would always return false.
If that is not the case, you would need to add the `newUser` claim as an output claim there.
It does seem like this is a password reset flow, in which the user will always exist already.
So `newUser` would always be false.

Comment: Hi @juunas, so in my `AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail-ProfileUpdate` I need to put the `<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" PartnerClaimType="newClaimsPrincipalCreated" />` again? In order to get it right, if ever its a new user? correct if me I'm wrong, I'm still new to custom policies.

Comment: Yes, that sounds correct.

Comment: It also needs to be an output claim in your RelyingParty element to appear in the ID token, like you have in the question.

Comment: Ohhhhh I get it now. One last question, do I still need to put the `newUser` output claim in `AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId`?

Comment: I think the read operations don't support this claim. It would be false in all cases there.